# is there a hostsman like app for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, hosts

> One way to keep malware and advertisements outside the door is by blocking
>   the computers that serve this content.... - [tweakers.net](http://tweakers.net/meuktracker/31412/hostsman-42.html)

[tweakers.net(Dutch)](http://tweakers.net/) was talking about [hostsman](http://www.abelhadigital.com/hostsman), according to them, can block the servers that are running malware advertisements and such.

**Question**: *Is there an app like that for Ubuntu?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **many apps, tools and solutions** for this purpose in the Linux world in general and  **Ubuntu** in particular, some of which might suit you, while some others might look too complicated ;-)

So, among a number of possible answers, I would cite just one of them; **hostsblock** which you can find here: [github.com: gaenserich/hostsblock](http://gaenserich.github.io/hostsblock/)

It has an easy manual installation procedure, but I've also created a **deb package** (which you can simply click and install) which should be in both ZIP and TAR files you can download from there. (Note: The deb file is under `/pkg/` subfolder, but it contains an old version (0.12.3) of hostsblock, which is now at 0.999.x)

It does more or less the same job as **hostsman** (updating your hosts file to prevent access to "undesirable" sites) but it only does it in the background almost without you noticing it ever ;-)

**UPDATE**: Now there's a **new** DEB package including a simple GUI -app indicator- with kwak daemon as well which is available here:

https://github.com/Sadi58/hostsblock/tree/master/indicator

[image]

Comment: Page not found for deb download link, could you please help me to install the package or any other alternative?

Comment: @Daniyal : Thanks for the warning; now updated above ⇧